# how to mock http error for angular2 testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, angular2-http

I am writing unit tests for an angular2 service. Code snippets:

```
// jasmine specfile

// already injected MockConnection into Http

backend.connections.subscribe ((c: MockConnection) => {
    connection = c;
});

// doing get-request
myServiceCallwithHttpRequest ().subscribe (result => {
    // this test passes!
    expect (result).toEqual ({
        "message": "No Such Object"
    });
    // this test fails, don't know how to get the response code
    expect (whereIsResponseStatus).toBe (404);
});

connection.mockRespond (new Response (new ResponseOptions ({
    body: {
        "message": "No Such Object"
    },
    status: 404
})));
```

my Service:

```
// service

myServiceCallwithHttpRequest (): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get ('/my/json-service').map (res => {
            // res.status == null
            return res.json ()
        })
        .catch (this.handleError); // from angular2 tutorial
}
```

The first expect is OK, the program goes into the map call, not the catch. But how do I get the status code 404? res.status is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works for me:

```
    mockConnection.mockRespond (new Response (new ResponseOptions ({
        body: {},
        status: 404
    })));
```

Comment: Did not work for me, this triggered the `NextObserver` instead of `ErrorObserver` in the  `subscribe` function.

Comment: same here , this does not call the failed observable handling case

Answer (score 37):

To get the mock error working, you need to import ResponseType from @angular/http and include the error type in the mock response, then extend Response and implement Error

```
import { Response, ResponseOptions, ResponseType, Request } from '@angular/http';
import { MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

class MockError extends Response implements Error {
    name:any
    message:any
}

...
handleConnection(connection:MockConnection) {
    let body = JSON.stringify({key:'val'});
    let opts = {type:ResponseType.Error, status:404, body: body};
    let responseOpts = new ResponseOptions(opts);
    connection.mockError(new MockError(responseOpts));
}
```

Comment: Thanks [amay0048](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3145286/amay0048), I've seen your solution on the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8961). This is working for me.

Comment: Thanks MAN. saved me.

Comment: Instead of creating the `MockError` class you can cast a `Response` to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) of Response and Error i.e. `connection.mockError(new Response(responseOpts) as Response & Error);`

Comment: @msdedwards Unions in TS were a bit whack when I first wrote this, but I would say that today this is the best option.

Comment: Using Angular 6... it would be good enough to do: `connection.mockError(new HttpErrorResponse({ status: 404, error: 'No Such Object'}));` by using `import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @lealceldeiro for sure, i think \@angular had only just been released when I wrote this

Answer (score 2):

Going over the source code at `node_modules\@angular\http\testing\mock_backend.d.ts`.
`MockConnection.mockRespond` is already in your code.
`MockConnection.mockError` is what you may need.
Play with it and see what you get.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote on this, after going through the definitions the way to get this working was indeed to use the mockError with a custom error class